# Test using async/await in truffle not working

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I am using node v12.13.1, truffle@5.1.8 and ubuntu 18.04 and running the test using documentation of async/await.

https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#using-async-await

This is my test code:

```
const DappTokenSale = artifacts.require("DappTokenSale");
const DappToken = artifacts.require("DappToken");


contract("DappToken", async accounts => {
    let dapptokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed();
    let dapptokenSale = await DappTokenSale.deployed();
    let admin = accounts[0]
    console.log(admin)
    let buyer = accounts[1]
    let tokenPrice = 1000000000000000; //wei (0.001 ether)
    // 3. Set the token available for sale
    let tokensAvailable = 750000;
    let numberOfTokens;
    it("Token buying", async() => {
        console.log(admin)
        let dapptokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed();
        console.log(dapptokenInstance.address, "hello")

    })

})
```

But there is no console.logs (e.g. console.log(admin))  when I run the tests.

[image]

Comment: try making changes to your contract. may be add a comment. If there is no change it will not recompile and hence redeploy.

Comment: Its compiling, but there is no console.log, says 0 passing

Comment: that is the tests result. what command are you entering?

Comment: truffle test, also truffle test ./test/testfile.js. Both are giving the same results

Comment: I see no obvious issue with your code. I tried with a local project and it works as expected. The problem might be somewhere else. Perhaps in the migration scripts, a bad truffle version, a dependency. Are you testing against ganache or a private blockchain? You might try forcing to recompile the contracts `truffle compile --all`.

Comment: No, not working. You are talking of which dependancy. I am using truffle@5.1.8 and ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
contract("DappToken", function(accounts) {
    it("Token buying", function() {
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            console.log(instance, 'instance');
        });
    });
});
```

This is my example in other smart contract, where the tests are running smoothly:

```
contract("CarData", function(accounts) {
    //setting up the account[1] will lead to revert, because account[1] is not allowed to call the method
    it('should revert the transaction of insertCarData when the from parameter is not the owner of the contract', function() {
        return CarData.deployed()
        .then(function (instance) {
            return instance.insertCarData("BG1234566", 1529767983, 1529767983, 1529767983, "1994", "Bulgaria", "Red", {from: accounts[0]});
        });
    });
});
```

It might be possible that console.logs are not showing when running the tests. Please try to run some method of your smart contract.

Comment: Ya, this method working fine, I have already tested. But not the async/await as given in documentation

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly fine:

```
const DappTokenSale = artifacts.require("DappTokenSale")
const DappToken = artifacts.require("DappToken")

contract("DappToken", async accounts => {
  let admin
  let buyer
  let tokenPrice = 1000000000000000 //wei (0.001 ether)
  // 3. Set the token available for sale
  let tokensAvailable = 750000
  let numberOfTokens
  it("Token buying", async () => {
    admin = accounts[0]
    buyer = accounts[1]
    console.log(admin, "Admin")
    console.log(buyer, "buyer")

    let dapptokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed()
    let dapptokenSale = await DappTokenSale.deployed()
    console.log(dapptokenInstance.address, "Token address")
    console.log(dapptokenSale.address, "Token Sale address")
  })
})
```

Seems one shouldn't include await DappToken.deployed() within the main outer contract function.